# How do I make catkin_make check for required python modules?

Tags: ros, catkin-make, package.xml, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like for catkin_make to fail if a fellow developer does not have all of the required python modules installed.  I thought that I could do this using the package.xml manifest, but I may just be doing something wrong.

I would like to make sure that another developer has the python "requests" module installed on their system, but it could be any other non-standard python module from apt-get or pip.

Am I on the right track?  Should I try to add something to CMakeLists.txt to get this behavior?

Here's a snippet of my package.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>awesome</name>
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>actionlib</build_depend>

  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>actionlib</run_depend>
  <run_depend>roslib</run_depend>

  <run_depend>os</run_depend>
  <run_depend>sys</run_depend>
  <run_depend>json</run_depend>
  <run_depend>yaml</run_depend>
  <run_depend>uuid</run_depend>
  <run_depend>boto3</run_depend>
  <run_depend>zipfile</run_depend>
  <run_depend>threading</run_depend>
  <run_depend>requests</run_depend>
</package>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241907/how-do-i-make-catkin_make-check-for-required-python-modules?/) by [travisariggs](https://answers.ros.org/users/26029/travisariggs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-08-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK, you cannot do this via `catkin_make`. You can however check with `rosdep check <PACKAGE_NAME>` if all packages are installed, or install them via `rosdep install <PACKAGE_NAME>`.
The `-v` flag turns on verbose output.

Note, however, that in the package.xml you need to have the respective rosdep keys, which are defined (here)[https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/python.yaml]. Many of the modules you specified are available in the python [standard library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/), thus you probably would not need to specify those.

For the `requests` module, you have to specify [`python-requests`](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/python.yaml#L1778-L1802) which gets resolved via `rosdep` for the different distributions.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1